# Description of window properties modified by wmctrl

Tags: window-manager, documentation, wmctrl

I found `wmctrl` allows for changing some "properties" of windows:

> ```
> wmctrl -r <WIN> -b ( add | remove | toggle),prop1 [,prop2 ]
>  Add, remove, or toggle up to two window properties simultaneously. The window that is being  
>  modified must be identified with a -r action. The property change is achived by using the 
>  request. The supported property names (for prop1 and prop2) are modal, sticky, maximized_vert,
>  maximized_horz, shaded, skip_taskbar, skip_pager, hidden, fullscreen, above and below. Two
>  properties are supported to allow operations like maximizing a window to full screen mode. 
>  Note that this action is made up of exactly two shell command line arguments.
> ```

**Is there any detailed description of what is each of these properties, and how does changing them affect windows behavior?**

Some are obvious, and/or can be easily understood by tinkering a bit, but some are not.
In any case, an official description is desirable.
The only thing I found (not official) is
https://blog.spiralofhope.com/1042/wmctrl-user-documentation-examples.html

Comment: Those are not so much a wmctrl - properties, but referring to application window properties (x). Think they are all listed here as far as I can see (further below): https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I read a bit further at this [specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html) and if this doesn't answer your Questions, I would only suggest to crawl through the Source-Code.

For Example

> _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR indicates that the window should not be included on a taskbar. This hint should be requested by the application, i.e. it indicates that the window by nature is never in the taskbar. Applications should not set this hint if _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE already conveys the exact nature of the window.

I think you should also note that not every Window-Manager ships with the same behaviour.

Comment: Your *here* tells exactly the same as the link I posted, and your *there* is simply `man`. None of them gives any more detail.
`man -P cat x | grep skip_` shows nothing, so I guess that is also not helpful.

Comment: Will check that. On a quick view, the explanation does not seem very illuminating. At any rate, I suggest editing the answer, instead of adding valuable info in comments.